# Tomcat Not invoking Controller api's

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, web-applications

I am new to spring and I am trying maven spring web application. 
when I try to call any API from controller on postman, I am getting `http status 404 not found`. But `index.jsp` is running on the home page of the webapp.

SpringConfig.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="employee" />
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.mongofunction.base.Repository"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mongofunction.base"/>


<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongo" />
</bean>
```

web.xml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/.*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Controller:

```
package com.mongofunction.base.Controller;

import com.mongofunction.base.ApplicationRuntimeException.ApplicationRuntimeException;
import com.mongofunction.base.DTO.EmployeeDTO;
import com.mongofunction.base.DTO.ResponseDTO;
import com.mongofunction.base.Service.EmployeeService;
import com.mongofunction.base.model.Employee;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseDTO add(EmployeeDTO employeeDTO)
    {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO=new ResponseDTO();
        try {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(employeeDTO, employee);
        if (employee.checkNull() != null)
            throw new ApplicationRuntimeException(employee.checkNull() + " Not Found");
        employee=employeeService.add(employee);
        if(employee==null)
            throw new ApplicationRuntimeException("Error Adding to Database");
        responseDTO.setValue("Added Successfully",HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }catch (ApplicationRuntimeException e)
    {
       responseDTO.setValue(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
    }
        return responseDTO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseDTO getAllEmployee()
    {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
        List<Employee> employeeList;
        try {
            employeeList=employeeService.getAll();
            if(employeeList==null||employeeList.isEmpty())
                throw new ApplicationRuntimeException("NO Records Found");
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("EmployeeList", employeeService.getAll());
            responseDTO.setData(jsonObject);
            responseDTO.setValue("Records Found", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseDTO.setValue(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return responseDTO;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseDTO getEmployee(@PathVariable String employeeId) {
        System.out.println(employeeId);
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {

            Employee employee = employeeService.get(employeeId);
            if(employee==null)
                throw new ApplicationRuntimeException("Record Not Found");
            responseDTO.setValue("Record Found", HttpStatus.OK);
            jsonObject.put("data", employee);
            responseDTO.setData(jsonObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseDTO.setValue(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        }
        return responseDTO;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseDTO updateEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();

        try {


            Employee employee = new Employee();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(employeeDTO, employee);
            if (employee.checkNull() != null)
                throw new ApplicationRuntimeException(employee.checkNull() + " Not Found");
            employee=employeeService.update(employee);
            if(employee==null)
                throw new ApplicationRuntimeException("Not Updated to the database");

            responseDTO.setValue("Updated Successfully", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseDTO.setValue(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY);
        }
        return responseDTO;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseDTO deleteEmployee(@PathVariable String employeeId) {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
        try {
            employeeService.delete(employeeId);
            responseDTO.setValue("Deleted Successfully", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseDTO.setValue(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return responseDTO;

    }


}
```

When I tried to call this URL through postman -> `localhost8080/MongoMaven/employee`, I get `http status 404 not found` error. 
(`MongoMaven` is the webapp folder name)

*I know spring boot is better to use but still i was asked to do this in spring data web app .*

Comment: No one who writes Spring these days uses XML bean configuration or version 3.0.  You should be using Spring Boot version 2.x and annotation configuration.  The person who asked you to write this in Spring 3 is wrong headed.  404 means your URLs are wrong.

Comment: our company project is still in spring , that is the reason why i have been asked to practice is this , a help would be really appreciated

Comment: Spring Boot is still Spring.  You need to upgrade that app, not practice an old idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Your `web.xml` seems wrong to me.
Can you try replacing it with:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>MongoMaven</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MongoMaven</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MongoMaven</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and then create another file named `MongoMaven-servlet.xml` in the same folder where `web.xml` is, and with contents as:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mongofunction.base" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <import resource="SpringConfig.xml"/>

</beans>
```

and check?

Comment: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [mongo]

This is the error i am getting currently from the configuration.xml

Comment: So following this answer helped in resolving the 404?

Comment: no , not actually , if i implement what you said i would have ended up with a MongoMaven-servlet.xml not found error , i added initparam path location for servlet.xml and then i got this error

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you please try it and and check?

Comment: Thank you for the replies . servlet initiation is successful . but you haven't mentioned about the datasource(Mongo) bean definition in this . Should i have to configure datasource in servlet.xml itself or should i have to do in separate xml file ?

Comment: From what I understand from your comments, you are not able to use the beans you have defined in `SpringConfig.xml`. I have updated the `MongoMaven-servlet.xml` in the answer so that it includes the beans mentioned in that file. Can you please try that out?